# PHPStorm 7 error with Live Edit

Tags: phpstorm

1)I just downloaded php storm EAP 7 and try implementing live Edit but it doesn't work. The error produced is " incompatible with this installation".

Comment: Really? Questions about a bug in an EAP? The v7/130.x builds thus far have been pretty buggy. Buggy enough for me to go back to v6.0.3 until a new build.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be kind of a no-answer:

I've had multiple issues with Live Edit and finally got the suggestion from the JetBrains support that I should turn it off because it interferes with the normal working of other componets. That being said, this was a few months ago, maybe the situation changed in the mean time.

I would suggest contacting their support, even if you don't have an (active) subscription, they tend to be very fast and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It works with the most current EAP Build.